# Loading java classes from JAR bytes in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I trying to load all java classes from JAR file bytes at runtime using JNI.
My code

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    long res = CreateJVM(&jvm, &env, "");

    jclass class_loader = env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassLoader");
    jobject system_loader = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(class_loader, env->GetStaticMethodID(class_loader, "getSystemClassLoader", "()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;"));
    jbyte* bytes = <bytes>


    // define all classes from this bytes
    env->DefineClass("Main", system_loader, bytes, sizeof(bytes));
    ...

    if (res == JNI_OK) {
        jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main");
        jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, NULL);
    }

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

I need to read bytes of a JAR file, convert them into jbytes and load all the java classes from those bytes to runtime

Like this code in java

```
final var classes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
try( final var inputStream = new JarInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( bytes ) ) )
{
  var entry = inputStream.getNextJarEntry();
  while( nonNull( entry ) )
  {
    var buffer = new bytes [entry.getSize()];
    inputStream.read( buffer, 0, entry.getSize()];
    classes.add( buffer );
    entry = inputStream.getNextJarEntry();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Java code doesn't load a jar properly. At least it doesn't define the classes or keep track of the names of the entries in the jar.

This works for all the jars I've tested in the past:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct JVM
{
    JavaVM* vm;
    JNIEnv* env;
};

JVM create_java_vm()
{
    const char* argv[] = {"-Djava.compiler=NONE",
                          "-Djava.class.path=."}; //"-verbose:jni"
    const int argc = static_cast<int>(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]));
    
    JavaVMInitArgs jvm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[argc];

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        options[i].optionString = const_cast<char*>(argv[i]);
    }

    JavaVM* vm = nullptr;
    JNIEnv* env = nullptr;
    JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&jvm_args);

    jvm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    jvm_args.nOptions = argc;
    jvm_args.options = options;
    jvm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    if (JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), &jvm_args) != JNI_OK)
    {
        return {vm, env};
    }
    return {vm, env};
}

bool load_jar(JNIEnv* env, const std::vector<std::uint8_t> &jar_data, bool ignore_exceptions = false)
{
    auto string_replace_all = [&](std::string str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) -> std::string {
        size_t start_pos = 0;
        while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
        }
        return str;
    };

    auto byte_array_input_stream = [](JNIEnv* env, const std::vector<std::uint8_t> &buffer) -> jobject {
        jbyteArray arr = env->NewByteArray(static_cast<jsize>(buffer.size()));
        if (arr)
        {
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(arr, 0, static_cast<jsize>(buffer.size()), reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(&buffer[0]));
            jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/io/ByteArrayInputStream");
            if (cls)
            {
                jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "([B)V");
                if (method)
                {
                    jobject result = env->NewObject(cls, method, arr);
                    if (result)
                    {
                        env->DeleteLocalRef(std::exchange(result, env->NewGlobalRef(result)));
                        env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
                        env->DeleteLocalRef(arr);
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
            }
            env->DeleteLocalRef(arr);
        }
        return nullptr;
    };

    auto jar_input_stream = [](JNIEnv* env, jobject input_stream) -> jobject {
        jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/util/jar/JarInputStream");
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V");
            if (method)
            {
                jobject result = env->NewObject(cls, method, input_stream);
                if (result)
                {
                    env->DeleteLocalRef(std::exchange(result, env->NewGlobalRef(result)));
                    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
                    return result;
                }
            }
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }
        return nullptr;
    };

    auto input_stream_read = [](JNIEnv* env, jobject input_stream) -> jint {
        jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(input_stream);
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "read", "()I");
            if (method)
            {
                jint result = env->CallIntMethod(input_stream, method);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
                return result;
            }
            
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }
        return -1;
    };

    auto byte_array_output_stream = [](JNIEnv* env) -> jobject {
        jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream");
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");
            if (method)
            {
                jobject result = env->NewObject(cls, method);
                if (result)
                {
                    env->DeleteLocalRef(std::exchange(result, env->NewGlobalRef(result)));
                    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
                    return result;
                }
            }
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }
        return nullptr;
    };

    auto output_stream_write = [](JNIEnv* env, jobject output_stream, jint value) {
        jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(output_stream);
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "write", "(I)V");
            if (method)
            {
                env->CallVoidMethod(output_stream, method, value);
            }
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }
    };

    auto byte_array_output_stream_to_byte_array = [](JNIEnv* env, jobject output_stream) -> std::vector<std::uint8_t> {
        jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(output_stream);
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "toByteArray", "()[B");
            if (method)
            {
                jbyteArray bytes = reinterpret_cast<jbyteArray>(env->CallObjectMethod(output_stream, method));
                if (bytes)
                {
                    void* arr = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(bytes, nullptr);
                    if (arr)
                    {
                        jsize size = env->GetArrayLength(bytes);
                        auto result = std::vector<std::uint8_t>(static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(arr),
                                                                static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(arr) + size);
                        env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(bytes, arr, 0);
                        env->DeleteLocalRef(bytes);
                        env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }
        return {};
    };

    auto get_next_jar_entry = [](JNIEnv* env, jobject jar_input_stream) -> jobject {
        jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(jar_input_stream);
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getNextJarEntry", "()Ljava/util/jar/JarEntry;");
            if (method)
            {
                jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(jar_input_stream, method);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(std::exchange(result, env->NewGlobalRef(result)));
                env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
                return result;
            }
            
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }
        return nullptr;
    };

    auto jar_entry_get_name = [](JNIEnv* env, jobject jar_entry) -> std::string {
        jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/util/jar/JarEntry");
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
            if (method)
            {
                jstring jstr = reinterpret_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(jar_entry, method));
                const char *name_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, 0);
                std::string result = std::string(name_string);
                env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, name_string);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(jstr);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
                return result;
            }
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }
        return std::string();
    };

    // Load the Jar
    jobject bais = byte_array_input_stream(env, jar_data);
    if (!bais)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Failed to open ByteArrayInputStream\n";
        return false;
    }

    jobject jis = jar_input_stream(env, bais);
    if (!jis)
    {
        env->DeleteGlobalRef(bais);
        std::cerr<<"Failed to open JarInputStream\n";
        return false;
    }

    // Read the jar entries
    jobject jar_entry = nullptr;
    const std::string extension = ".class";

    while((jar_entry = get_next_jar_entry(env, jis)))
    {
        std::string name = jar_entry_get_name(env, jar_entry);
        if ((name.length() > extension.length()) && (name.rfind(extension) == name.length() - extension.length()))
        {
            jobject baos = byte_array_output_stream(env);
            if (!baos)
            {
                std::cerr<<"Failed to open ByteArrayOutputStream for: "<<name<<"\n";
                if (!ignore_exceptions)
                {
                    env->DeleteGlobalRef(jar_entry);
                    env->DeleteGlobalRef(jis);
                    env->DeleteGlobalRef(bais);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Define the class
            jint value = -1;
            while((value = input_stream_read(env, jis)) != -1)
            {
                output_stream_write(env, baos, value);
            }
            
            std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes = byte_array_output_stream_to_byte_array(env, baos);
            
            std::string canonicalName = string_replace_all(string_replace_all(name, "/", "."),
                                                            ".class",
                                                            std::string());
            
            jclass cls = env->DefineClass(string_replace_all(name, ".class", "").c_str(),
                                            nullptr, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(bytes.data()),
                                            static_cast<jint>(bytes.size()));
            
            if (cls)
            {
                std::cerr<<"Defined: "<<canonicalName<<" Size: "<<bytes.size()<<"\n";
                env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr<<"Failed to define: "<<canonicalName<<"  Size: "<<bytes.size()<<"\n";
                if (env->ExceptionCheck())
                {
                    env->ExceptionDescribe();
                    env->ExceptionClear();

                    if (!ignore_exceptions)
                    {
                        env->DeleteGlobalRef(jar_entry);
                        env->DeleteGlobalRef(jis);
                        env->DeleteGlobalRef(bais);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr<<"Skipping Resource: "<<name<<"\n";
        }
        
        env->DeleteGlobalRef(jar_entry);
    }
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(jis);
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(bais);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    JVM jvm = create_java_vm();
    if (!jvm.vm)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Failed to Create JavaVM\n";
        return 0;
    }

    if (load_jar(jvm.env, some_jar_as_bytes, true))
    {
        std::cout<<"Jar loaded successfully\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr<<"Failed to load Jar\n";
    }

    jvm.vm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```